# Change dataframe in R to a specific format in a JSON file

Tags: json, r, dataframe

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFaGX.png)

This link is a screenshot of a data frame that I have in R and I am having difficulty transferring it into a JSON file with this format:

```
{"id2": 1, "x": [0,0,0,0,0,1,0]}
{"id2": 1, "x": [0,0,1,0,0,1,1]}
```

And so on…

I’ve been trying to use the `tojson()` function in R as well as some other things I have found online but nothing seems to be working. Any guidance on this would be very helpful. There are 47 columns and 10000 rows total so doing things manually could take a while.

Comment: Please `dput` a piece of your data, do not link to data... especially if those links are with pictures...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example , using a sample data frame similar to yours.

```
library(jsonlite)

# Create sample data frame
> d1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),B=c(0,1), C=c(1,0), D=c(0,0))


# Add a column concatenating B,C and D
> d1$x <- with(d1, paste(B, C, D,sep=","))
> d1
  id B C D     x
1  1 0 1 0 0,1,0
2  2 1 0 0 1,0,0
> 

# Add opening and closing square brackets
> d1$x <- with(d1, paste("[",x,sep = ""))
> d1
  id B C D      x
1  1 0 1 0 [0,1,0
2  2 1 0 0 [1,0,0
> d1$x <- with(d1, paste(x,"]",sep = ""))

> d1
  id B C D       x
1  1 0 1 0 [0,1,0]
2  2 1 0 0 [1,0,0]
> 

#  Subset the columns we need
> d2 <- d1[,c("id","x")]
> d2
  id       x
1  1 [0,1,0]
2  2 [1,0,0]

# create JSON
> x <- toJSON(d2)
> x
[{"id":1,"x":"[0,1,0]"},{"id":2,"x":"[1,0,0]"}]
```